# Kotlin ActivityMainBinding build id in for loop

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a problem. In my xml file, I have multiple textViews with the following id's:

```
txtRow1Column1
txtRow1Column2
txtRow2Column1
txtRow2Column2
txtRow3Column1
txtRow3Column2
txtRow4Column1
txtRow4Column2
```

Now I filled an array with random numbers between 1..2 and using the 1 or 2 I want to add a text in the textview from the resources. For that I already have the following function:

```
private fun startNewRound() {

    // Define the array for (row, column, value)
    val rows = arrayOf<Array<Int>>();

    // Fill the array for each row and for each column
    for (row in 1..4) {
        rows.set(row, emptyArray())
        for (column in 1..2) {
            rows[row].plus((1..2).random())
        }
    }

    // Show the correct text using the filled array
    for (columns in rows) {
        for (value in columns) {
            val id = "txtRow" + rows.indexOf(columns) + "Column" + (columns.indexOf(value) + 1)
            when (value) {
                1 -> binding."ID HERE".text = getString(R.string.strTrue)
                2 -> binding."ID HERE".text = getString(R.string.strFalse)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Currently I have added `"ID HERE"` instead of the id of the view, because I need to use a string as id to bind to the view. My question is: How can I use that string to find the correct id and be able to bind to that specific view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Side note, the way you're building that 2D array looks like *O(n^2)*, even if it wasn't going to throw IndexOutOfBoundsExceptions.

The way you're getting the column index won't work. Suppose you have the value 1 twice in a column. `indexOf` is going to return 0 both times because it returns the first valid match. Also, using `indexOf` inside your 2D loop results in *O(n^3)* complexity when it could just be *O(n)*.

As to your problem, you can use `Resources.getIdentifier()` to find the Int ID of a view so you can find the view using `findViewById`. The alternative would be to use reflection on the binding class to find a field with that name, but that's uglier.

```
fun <T> View.getChildWithName(name: String): T {
    val id = context.resources.getIdentifier("id", name, context.packageName)
    return findViewById(id)
}

private fun startNewRound() {

    val rows = Array(4) { Array(2) { (1..2).random() } }

    rows.forEachIndexed { rowIndex, row ->
        row.forEachIndexed { colIndex, value ->
            val id = "txtRow${rowIndex + 1}Column${colIndex  + 1}" 
            val view = binding.root.getChildWithName<TextView>(id)
            view.text = when (value) {
                1 -> getString(R.string.strTrue)
                2 -> getString(R.string.strFalse)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes!!! This worked, only you need to switch the `name` and `"id"`